# Is it possible to install the Android browser and email app if they weren't built-in?

Tags: email, browser

As far as I know, older Android tablets/smartphones have the Android web browser and email app as their built-in web browser and email app.

But my Android smartphone does not have those. My Android smartphone's built-in web browser and email app are Google Chrome and Gmail. I guess that is because the version of Android OS of my Android smartphone is a bit newer (Android 7.0).

Is it possible for my Android smartphone to install the Android web browser and email app?

Comment: As you probably know, Android is a Google owned company ( through some nearly illegal trickery with creating two company's, that's a different subject however ) since they create Chrome and Gmail they'll always be pushing their own content on Androids ( Gmail, YouTube, Chrome, Etc... ) . If you would like to install the older browser and email application, you'll need to know what Android version you had previously, the browser changes with each new Android version.  Try looking up AOSP Android browser for the version you have now. Go back through the release versions until it suits your needs

Comment: P.S     Older browsers will lower your level of security hypothetically, This is due to unforseen bugs and vulnerabilities that may have been fixed for newer versions. Keep that in mind with any downgrade of software.

Comment: @Zillinium So it looks like it's not possible to simply do the installation without downgrading. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock Android browser and email app were discontinued since KitKat :

- [Google puts Android’s stock e-mail app in the Play Store](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/06/google-puts-androids-stock-e-mail-app-in-the-play-store/)
- [Android 4.4+ KitKat ships without browser app. OEMs have to license Chrome or build their own](http://www.unwiredview.com/2013/11/21/android-4-4-kitkat-ships-without-browser-app-oems-have-to-license-chrome-or-build-their-own/)

They have been replaced by Gmail and Chrome as commented. Even if you are willing to face security risk to have it installed you can't downgrade from Nougat to KitKat (extremely unlikely). Only option left is to run a device of pre KiKat OS having those stock apps

Answer (score 3):

if you are really interested in installing those previous applications; you may download their apk files from reliable resource and put them in your phone SD card or internal memory.
once done, go to security options in your Android Settings and check Unknown Sources checkbox.
Now open your file Manager application of android phone or download from Playstore. After that open file from FileManager, it will ask to install the Application; agree the terms and install one by one; both of your required applications.

Dear be very sure to download apk files from reliable resource, as there might be compatibility issues and more security risks. And i'll be not liable of any damage to your device and Data.

This is the most easiest solution. Thank You

Comment: Thank you. My purpose was to test web pages and email templates in those two apps. I'm a web developer, by the way. I would give it a try when I really have to do the testings on my smartphone.